# only print the first found string in textfile with python

Tags: python

is there a way to print first string only when it found the string? example:

textfile:

```
date....
author:...
this is a list:
there a string 1 here
and there a string 2 there
but also have string 3 here
don't have string 4 there
```

code:

```
for line in open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r").readlines():
    if line.find('string') != -1:
        print "found ", line
```

printed:

```
found there a string 1 here
```

Comment: can you explain more?? its not clear, first string??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `break` to stop cycle. And `in` to check substring.

```
for line in open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r").readlines():
    if 'string' in line:
        print("found "+line)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way using `with`:

```
with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename),'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'string' in line: 
            print("found ", line)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Little modification to your code:

```
for line in open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r").readlines():
    if line.find('string') >=0:
        print "found ", line
        break                       # to stop loop when string is found
```

`find` returns position of string found else -1